# How can i insert into multiple tables using Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

How can i Insert record into multiple tables using Linq?

I have three related tables `Contact`, `Phone` and `Email`, Is it possible to  create Contact first then Phone or Email. Since Phone and Email use ContactID as a foreign Key

Here is my linq expression looks like:

```
 var Contact = Mapper.Map<Contact>(request.CreateContactInformation);
    Contact.CreatedBy = request.CreateContactInformation.CreatedBy;
    Contact.CreatedDate = SystemClock.UtcNow;
    Contact.UpdatedBy = request.CreateContactInformation.UpdatedBy;
    Contact.UpdatedDate = SystemClock.UtcNow;

    await Context.AddAsync(Contact);
    await Context.SaveChangesAsync();

    var phones = Mapper.Map<Phone>(request.CreateContactInformation);
    phones.ContactID = Contact.ID;
    phones.PhoneNumber = request.CreateContactInformation.PhoneNumber;     
    Context.AddAsync(phones);
    await Context.SaveChangesAsync();


    var email = Mapper.Map<Email>(request.CreateContactInformation);
    email.ContactID = Contact.ID;
    email.EmailAddress = request.CreateContactInformation.Email;
    Context.AddAsync(email);
    await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But i get this exception error

> InternalServerError. Error Content: System.ArgumentException: Cannot
>   create an instance of abstract type ....EF.Base.BaseEntity. (Parameter
>   'type') at ...AsyncTransactionInterceptor.InterceptAsync[T](Task`1
>   task, String methodName)

Comment: Look like we need more detail about your model to resolve the problem.If there're some abstract method in the model.

Comment: Please share your model and the mapped model.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about what your context actually is. But I guess your Add function might look like :

```
  await Context.Contact.AddAsync(Contact);
```

Since you are not specifying which table to insert. And in other AddAsync() function , you need to enclose it by await.  Or it'll still be a Task , and will not be invoked.

Comment: Thank you Talesa!, i tried that still gives me the same error